# Not able to send blob file to server using ws.send(blob)

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, websocket

I'm trying to send a canvas paint to a server (running nodejs) through 'ws' web socket. I'm not able to figure it out why I'm not able to receive the blob file  on the server side.

SERVER CODE:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server,
  wss = new WebSocketServer({
    port: 8080
  });
wss.on('connection', function(ws) {

  ws.on("message", function message(data, flags) {

    console.log('received: %s', data;
    }

  });

});
```

CLIENT CODE:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8080");


timer = setInterval(
  function() {
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
    var data = canvas.get()[0].toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
    var newblob = dataURItoBlob(data);
    ws.send(newblob); //sending blob file
  }, 50);
```

Comment: Are there any error messages you can include in your post? What steps did you take? Also, where is `canvas` defined? It seems to be using jQuery functions but is it really a jQuery object?

Comment: Hi Carl ! (1) No error msgs so far. The web-socket is open and is receiving string msgs but not blob file. (2) I'm trying to initiate live camera through a JavaScript. After initiating, I'm painting it on an canvas element. Through canvas element, I'm using every single painted frame and converting to a blob file and sending it to the nodejs server. The only problem is that server isn't able to receive blob file or alternatively the ws.send(blob) isn't working out.....Please refer to this link for full HTML and JavaScript code. Any suggestions ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31160933/how-to-convert-blob-file-into-a-stream-for-opencv-face-detection

Comment: 1) Are you implement `dataURItoBlob` function? 2) Change way get dataURL: ` var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);`

Comment: @stdob-- I tried your suggestion. It didn't work. I've switched to getImageData function and then I'm creating Uint8Array to store the data and then sending it over ws socket. This way, I've at-least started receiving the data ('undefined' type) whose value is :-

Comment: Initially i thought that this is the binary image data that I've received from client browser and now to test the data validity, I'm sending the same data back from the server to client and trying to render it on html using createImageData and  
ctx.putImageData functions but I can't see anything happening....Seems like the image doesn't exist at all....Any suggestions @CarlK ??

Comment: Value:- <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ... >

Comment: Show the entire client code.